# asp.net fast query of Global Address List

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap, gal

What I need to do is realize query of GAL from webpage. I tried standard way (Querying LDAP with `DirectoryServices`), but it doesn't help me very much because of huge amount of records in GAL (approx. 150 000). What I need is to get user info for the following query:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(SAMAccountName=*{0}*)(displayname=*{0}*)(userprincipalname=*{0}*))),
```

where `{0}` stands for data I've got from user.

Outlook does such things very fast. I guess it stores data somewhere, and somehow syncs it with GAL.

What I am trying to do is to maintain synchronized copy of GAL (only 3 fields I need), but I don't know how to generate a query for "new" items, for example users added in the last week.

Is there a way to get such information?

Comment: Do you need the wildcard stars?

Comment: yes, without them I have acceptable time (like 10-15 seconds) to get answers.

Comment: So the wildcards are slowing it down, may i suggest and exact match then re-run with wildcard if no matches found?

Outlook syncs the address book daily, maybe you could cache it in a dataset then using dataset filtering?

Comment: like I said, I just will get all info from ldap to sql every day, but I need to get only new (or changed) items from LDAP so I would not reupload 150000 items every day.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend figuring out how to make the LDAP queries responsive because I highly doubt that Outlook caches this data.  You might want to look at [Ambiguous Name Resolution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243299?wa=wsignin1.0) as a starting place.

That being said, you want to add a parameter to your search for either the `whenChanged` attribute or the `whenCreated` attribute.  You can take a look at [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/01/25/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-objects-that-have-been-added-to-active-directory-since-a-specified-date.aspx) to find out how to search from one of these attributes.